# jQuery autcomplete not displaying

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I've looked through many of the previous posts about this, but I think mine is much more simple than what I've found. My field is requesting data successfully, but is not displaying it. I would assume this is related to the CSS to display it. I'm using the jQuery UI CSS to display it, as I do on other sites I've designed:

```
<link href="/css/console/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Here is where I'm trying to display it. What am I doing wrong here? I've got this working on other sites.

```
<input type="text" name="userSearch" id="userSearch"/>
<input class="button" style="top: -1px; margin-left: 5px;" type="button" value="SEARCH" />
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenUserWom" value="" /></span></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#userSearch').autocomplete({
            source: '/console/ajax/user_search_autocomplete.php',
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#userSearch").val(ui.item.label); 
                $("#hiddenUserWom").val(ui.item.id);
        }
      });

      $(document).ready( function () {
          $("#userSearch").focus();
      });
      </script>
```

Here is the successful returned data:
This is an example of the return:

[ { "label": "5U5NU - Devin Parker - Vacaville, CA", "id": "5U5NU" }]

Description of data format for jQuery UI as taken from the official site:

> Expected data format
>
> The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two
>   variants:
>
> An Array of Strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ] An Array of Objects with
>   label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" },
>   ... ]

This should work properly.

Here is the site: http://wombusiness.com/console/members/

It's the power search field that needs to autocomplete.

Comment: @ harhahu - I don't think you understand how this works.  Can anyone help me here?   Obviously, I would want to display the VALUE of the clicked element in the search field on select.  What else could be going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Put your autocomplete inside your $(document).ready

```
<input type="text" name="userSearch" id="userSearch"/>
<input class="button" style="top: -1px; margin-left: 5px;" type="button" value="SEARCH" />
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenUserWom" value="" /></span></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready( function () {
  $('#userSearch').autocomplete({
        source: '/console/ajax/user_search_autocomplete.php',
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#userSearch").val(ui.item.label); 
            $("#hiddenUserWom").val(ui.item.id);
    }
  });
      $("#userSearch").focus();
  });
  </script>
```

Problem #2 $("#userSearch").val(ui.item.label);
You are overwriting your autocomplete with its own data.

Comment: Why is an attribute on the input-field `autocomplete="off"`?

Comment: Didn't work.  Data is being returned successfully, but no display.

Comment: @mavrick - Where is that at?  I don't have that applied to any fields.

Comment: in your select try using an alert(ui.item.label)

Comment: @harhahu - Select won't execute if the list to select from never shows up in the first place.  I need the list of results to display.

Comment: @Devin I just informed myself, it's an attribute to disable the browser-autocomplete.

Comment: do you have any other userSearch fields on the same page?

Comment: @har - If you look at the source code you can verify there is no other element with that id on the page.  It's very simple code, I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: @mav - Yeah I don't have the attribute assigned to any fields.

Comment: you are getting no script errors on bottom left status bar? What browser are you using?

Comment: $("#userSearch").val(ui.item.label);  You are overwriting your own autofill!

Comment: What?  That's on SELECT.  How can I select something if it's not displaying in the first place?  That can't have anything to do with it...

Comment: Select is an event that is fired on your user action of a clicking an element.  An action to do on a select would be take the items data and put it in a hidden field.  _im sorry but i must return to work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9240/discussion-between-devin-and-harhahu)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the return from the PHP. If you try the exact same but with a fixed set in an array as source the autocomplete works perfect.

The JSON encoding seems fine.

I know you don't need it or use it, but please try adding a `value` to each item. I'm not sure, but the `value` might be a required field, and it'll be easier for you to test it than it would be for me.